# Oracle - LAST_DAY and TRUNC - order of execution

Tags: oracle, datetime, plsql, oracle19c

I am getting unexpected result when using combination of `LAST_DAY` and `TRUNC`:

```
select LAST_DAY(TRUNC(sysdate, 'DAY')) from dual;
--31-JUL-2021 00:00:00

select TRUNC(LAST_DAY(sysdate), 'DAY')from dual;
--26-JUL-2021 00:00:00
```

Why these calls does not return same results? I mean, what is the difference between:

1. I want today to be truncated (get rid of hours)
2. Then get last day of the month

And

1. I want last day of the month (with hour)
2. And then get rid of the hour part

Comment: Just to back up the answer that's been given; the [documentation shows the behaviour](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/ROUND-and-TRUNC-Date-Functions.html#GUID-8E10AB76-21DA-490F-A389-023B648DDEF8) for the different format elements. It also notes that 'DAY' is NLS-sensitive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TRUNC(datestamp, 'DAY')` gets you the first day of the week containing the `datestamp`. Weird but true.

If you want the day of the datestamp, simply use `TRUNC(datestamp)`.

Oracle datestamps are floating-point numbers under the hood.

Comment: Oh my god, you are absolutely right with the 'DAY' part :D 'DD' is what I was looking for... Totally missed that. thanks!

Comment: @O. Jones. a slight correction. Oracle dates (timestamps) are not floating point numbers, but an internal byte array of integers (7 bytes for date, 11-13 bytes for timestamps). [See](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/oracle-dates-timestamps-and-intervals). You can get a glimpse of this running `select sysdate, dump(sysdate) from dual;`  It is correct that date *arithmetic* in handed with floating point arithmetic as 1 indicates a day thus half-a-day is .5 and a quarter-of-a-day as .25, etc.